# Удаление записей таблицы с помощью таблицы шаблона

Tags: sql

Вопрос заключается в следующем, имеем исходную таблицу откуда нужно удалить несколько записей и имеем другую таблицу в которой есть точные копии записей из исходной. Нужно с помощью этой таблицы удалить все копии из исходной.

Теперь разъяснение с примером того что я хочу. Смотрим рисунок для наглядности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е берем исходную таблицу и выбираем из нее:

SELECT id FROM исходная_таблица WHERE id = 2 OR id = 3;

Теперь нужно удалить из нее то что получили и нужно сделать это за раз. Я это вижу так:

DELETE FROM исходная_таблица WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM исходная_таблица WHERE id = 2 OR id = 3);

естественно что получим ошибку потому что типы данных в условии разные.

Но ведь это должно как то просто решатся средствами языка.

Опыта у меня не хватает, поделитесь кому не жалко.

Comment: ну правильно. как минимум зачем во втором запросе звездочка? ...... что ты надеялся получить вот тут `WHERE id = ( ... )` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский опечатался. В реале там id. posgre пишит: ОШИБКА:  подзапрос в выражении вернул больше одной строки

Comment: Зачем вообще подзапрос, если работает  обычный `DELETE FROM исходная_таблица WHERE id = 2 OR id = 3`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а потому что таблица по которой происходит удаление собрана из нескольких таблиц. А в вопросе просто пример

Comment: так надо нормальные исходные данные, а не такие как ты думаешь что должно быть.......потому что в исходном виде вопрос решается запросом выше..

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и никак по другому сделать нельзя?

Comment: `ОШИБКА: подзапрос в выражении вернул больше одной строки` - вот.... всё верно... потому  что  в `WHERE id =` может быть лишь один параметр...... для множества есть `WHERE id IN(...)`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вот это я у вас и выпрашивал )

Comment: еще, говорят, джойны в некоторых случаях работают быстрее, чем `IN` так что можно это написать с джойнами если идентификаторов реально много.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мой сусанин мне доказывает обратное .. За joinы спасибо вы подтвердили о том что я правильно думаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть немного другой синтаксис удаления, с его помощью все сильно проще:

```
delete
from table1
from [исходная таблица] as table1
     inner join [таблица с удаляемыми значениями] as table2
             on table1.id = table2.id
```

синтаксис написан для MS SQL, для других СУБД должен быть похожим. Смысл в том, что вы выбираете только те строки, которым есть соответствие во второй таблице и удаляете только их.

Comment: хорошо спасибо завтра попробую. если поможет ответ помечу как правильный

Comment: да действительно можно удалять так вы сказали. только в postgreesql вместо join надо использовать USING